# how to change width div with animation jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two div's that one `display:block` and another `display:none`. (first div has block display and second div has none display also first div bigger than second div)
also I have two buttons.

I want, that when i click the second buttom my first div get small, and than change to second div with animation.

please guide me about it

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: have a look at [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the scripts refrence to your page then

You can define your second button click method

```
<script type="text/jscript">

 $('#ButtonID').click(function (e)
     {   
     //Make the first div smaller     
     $('#FirstDivID').attr('height','lesservalue');
     $('#FirstDivID').attr('width','lesservalue');
     //change the display property of the second div to make it visible
     $('#SecondDivID').attr('Display','block');
   });

</script>
```